# Request for Meta

Tags: discussion, feature-request, meta, per-site-meta

In relation to other metas, this site should transform to "Stack Exchange Meta". This includes the following modifications:

- It should really *be* a meta. Now it really *is* a main.
- Posts move from Meta SE to SE Meta.
- Its acronym transforms to "Meta".
- Users automatically register, as it is the meta of "SE".
- Events move too.
- Badges move. No additional "meta" badges earned.
- Rep here becomes rep on SE.
  Right now there is no "general reputation", however there is an "association bonus", i.e. when you know how SE technically works (buttons, close reasons, flags, comments, badges, etc.)
- URL is the same.

Comment: Are there any problems that this is aiming to solve?

Comment: @TIPS There is confusion that needs to be solved, at least.

Comment: In that case, @OP you need to prove there is a sizable portion of users being confused by this, with some data or evidence from here and there.

Comment: @TIPS Who is `@OP`? You can't do that, you don't notify anyone *extra* here. Also, if a commenter was named `OP` or `O P`, you would notify them this way.

Comment: OP means "**O**riginal **P**oster", i.e. you.

Comment: @TIPS `@OP` means nothing though. As I said before, you're not notifying anyone extra, or a previous commenter in this case. Also, there isn't such a shorthand.

Comment: I'm pinging you, and that's all there's to it. It's not supposed to do anything special. It's just a normal vocative with some internet tuning to it. Please focus on the main problem here. Do you have any evidence that this is a source of confusion among users?

Comment: @TIPS (not pinging *me*) [Li'l evidence](/q/280507#comment910796_280508)

Comment: It's not clear why the current name is confusing.....

Comment: @Ramhound I feel like "Meta.SE" should be a main site for all metas, "Meta.Meta" its meta, "StackExchangeMain.SE" a main site about all mains, and "StackExchangeMain.Meta" its meta.

Comment: Now that would be an unnecessarily specific and confusing separation.

Comment: It would be very nice if this proposal somehow addressed the distressing tendency for SO users (and even occasionally others from around the network) to treat Meta as though it were an entirely different site, the one they're used to. But as far as I can tell, it doesn't, and that's the one issue that would seem to be worth solving in this area!

Comment: @NathanO'TᴇstingTuggy Edited.

Answer (score 14):

> the main site being stackexchange.com

Which is different to all other meta sites that are attached to a Q&A site. stackexchange.com is not a Q&A site.

As for Area51 - it too needs its own place to discuss the site itself. Hence discuss.area51. I don't really see what that has to do with it.

---

But that all disregards the main issue with your proposal here - it isn't solving any problems.

That is - please explain what the problem that your proposal is trying to fix. I don't see a problem statement, just a request to discuss something that appears to me to have little value.

Comment: It would be a Q&A site about the StackExchange network, not a Q&A site where we just get support about our problems with the StackExchange network.

Comment: So what Q/A would you ask there that wouldn't fit here?

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος - I am confused. This site provides both functions you are talking about (you can discuss the network here on this site, as well as get support here). What exactly are you suggesting then? That we remove the support function (which, by the way, is something that all meta sites do - they are also there for support to the site users)?

Comment: @Oded The name is a bit confusing, so we should change it to "Stack Exchange Q&A" or something. The name "Meta" actually implies this is a meta site, which is technically not.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος - again. What problem would that solve? Why is the current state of affairs a problem? The name of the site is "Meta", in the same way that the gaming site is called "Arqade".

Comment: @Oded Does not make sense to me. If I take it as is, "Meta" would be a name for a BIIG META SITE! If you think this isn't helping, then we could just use discuss.stackexchange.com, just like in Area 51. I know it doesn't make sense, but the name "Meta" actually confuses me. Also, I thought of it as "a site for discussing about the Stack Exchange network", not "a practical meta of the main site of the Stack Exchange network". If the name should remain unchanged, then I'm really confused with it.

Comment: It is simply a name. I am guessing from your display name that you are Greek, and therefore, Meta has specific meaning to you, in your day-to-day. But - we are not just going to change it because you, specifically, are confused, @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος

Comment: @Oded Yes, I am Greek, but this seems to be the only meta-less main Q&A site. Makes sense though, so, on a second thought, I'm deleting the question. (flag for moderator attention, except if you can delete this answer)

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος I don't get how Meta.SE is philosophically different from, say, Meta.SO or Meta.English.se. It *is* a meta site, it *is* a "big meta site" for stack exchange as a whole. People post suggestions for SE sites here, they settle disputes, they ask for support .... just like any other meta site on the network. The only difference is Meta.SE isn't a meta for any specific site, it's a meta for *all* of them. It's a meta site for the network as a whole. What's confusing about the name, then?

Comment: It's *technically* different, i.e. low-reps can edit non-wiki posts.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος I'm not sure that's true. I've made edits here, and had to wait for them to be approved. Just like any other site. That's how I earn my first 2 rep points on Meta, actually. Can you elaborate as to how you view it differently from any other meta? Give specifics / details.

Comment: @DanBron I mean, you can't suggest an edit on a non-wiki post. Here, I can ask questions with <5 rep (without association bonus) (if I remember well), and up/downvotes affect your rep, for example.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος I can and have suggested edits on non-wiki posts here. And yeah, the <5 points thing is because this site is the "bottom" (or "top") site in the network: the last resort of a user who is suffering problems, so people have a place to go even if they're brand new or have been knocked down to 1 rep. If they get shut down here, that's it, they've used up their last chance. But that, and the voting-affecting-rep thing seem like minor details to me, and don't impinge on the site's meta status or name. I'm still confused as to why you're confused.

Comment: @DanBron Basically it's the URL regex: `^meta\.[...]*\.?stackexchange.com`, with `[...]` symbolizing "the rest". So `meta.stackexchange.com` should make no difference, because it's matched. But, it makes! So, that's why I'm confused.

Comment: Well, we are going to change that URL regex soon to: `^[a-z-]+\.meta\.stackexchange\.com`, @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος - so... would you still be confused?

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος What? From "make no difference", I can only infer you mean this site (Meta Stack Exchange) is *not* different from any other meta, so now I'm even *more* confused as to why you asked this question (in which it appears you *do* think Meta.SE is different from the other metas). Can you elaborate on *how you think Meta.SE is meaningfully different from the other metas*? Is it really just that one can ask questions with 4 or fewer rep points, and that voting impacts reputation? Is that really enough to make Meta.se *categorically* different to you? Really?

Comment: @Oded Yep, because this appears to be a main site, even though it's called "meta". Consider `stackexchange.com` as a normal non-Q&A main site, on its own domain. It has got the most subdomains and subsubdomains (i.e. unix, chemistry, cooking...). I suggest for the *name* of this particular site to be changed to "Stack Exchange Meta", and *be* a meta, not a main. I'm not concerned with other metas.

Comment: @DanBron I said it *should* not make any difference, but it *does*.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος Ok, it finally clicked for me. Two things bug you. First, that the "meta" in the URL is *on the same level* as "english" or "chemistry" or "cooking", and to you that means it should be a "main Q&A" site. And second, that the *word order* in "Meta StackExchange" is reversed from the word order in other metas, like "Chemistry Meta" or "Physics Meta". That those were your complaints eluded me for the longest time. Now that I know what you're saying, I can just say "it makes sense to me", and let it rest.

Comment: @DanBron You got it **all wrong**. I said Stack Exchange should be a main site, and the meta should be called "Stack Exchange Meta", not reversed. This *should* be a meta, not a main. Also, the `meta.stackexchange.com` confuses me because I expect a meta, and I get a main instead.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος I think there's a language barrier here. I was detailing *what bothers you*, i.e. what you *don't like*. So yes, I now understand what you're asking. I don't agree, but I'm a hell of a lot less confused.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος you miss the basic fact that this site is already called MSE, which stands for.... wait for this... Meta Stack Exchange. So your whole suggestion is to switch the order of the words??

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes, the acronym is based on the URL though, not the name. The URL remains, so MSE is MSE.

Comment: @DanBron Actually, I'm not that confused anymore, I was when I discovered this site, thinking it is really a meta.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος As we discussed before, *it really is a meta*. It really is. It's a *meta for the network*. People post the *same kinds of questions here they do on any other meta*, except those questions do/must apply to the network as a whole, i.e. all sites, not any specific site. If the question applies to aome specific site, it's posted on that site's meta. If it applies to all sites, then it's posted here. But that's the only difference; in all other ways, the question is still a Meta-question.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος no it's not because of the URL. This site is actually the meta site for whole of Stack Exchange. All sites, and the engine which is behind them.

Comment: @DanBron I mean technically, not philosophically.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος The name and URL do not make the site "technically not a meta", in fact in this case they make it "technically a meta". The only differences you've pointed out, the "<5 rep for questions" thing and the "votes impact rep" thing are not because "the site is really a main", they are *consciously and deliberately imposed for specific reasons* to help shape how the site is used. This site is a meta, technically, philosophically, categorically. Full stop. Welcome to Meta StackExchange!

Comment: @ShadowWizard MSO and MSF are examples. They mean "Stack Overflow Meta" and "Server Fault Meta" respectively.

Comment: @DanBron Just a spelling correction; `Thai` -> `this`.

Comment: If you delete this answer, I'll be able to delete this question... Right now I can't do so...

Comment: Not going to delete an answer that at least 14 people found useful. Not going to delete a question/answer pair that has information for people who may be interested in them.

Comment: @Oded Sorry, I just now saw that you had replied, but, how is anything in my question useful at all (it has a -42 score)? Yes, the answer might be useful, but the question is not useful at all. And, I remember being the immature guy I was back then when I asked the question, being bothered by small issues.

Comment: It is useful in that it shows the community sentiment at this time, @Έρικ - and as you said - it has useful answers, which would also get deleted at that point.